# Access Docker secret from application in Windows container

Tags: windows, docker, docker-secrets

We're running Docker Enterprise 18.09.8 on Windows Server 2019.  Our application is built using Express and running as a service in a Docker container in a swarm.  Our images need to be small, so they're built on Windows nano, which means no Powershell.  We have an API key for a service we're using that should be kept private, so we planned to use Docker secrets to make that API key available to the application.

Unfortunately, the application can't read the Docker secret.  If I use:

```
docker exec -it 8528f64a022e cmd.exe
```

I can see there's something present at:

```
C:\ProgramData\Docker\secrets\search_credentials
```

but I can't read it.  If I use instead:

```
docker exec -it --user ContainerAdministrator 8528f64a022e cmd.exe
```

I can type the content of the file.

The core of the issue appears to be this from [Manage sensitive data with Docker secrets - Windows Support](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/#windows-support):

> When creating a service which uses Windows containers, the options to specify UID, GID, and mode are not supported for secrets. Secrets are currently only accessible by administrators and users with system access within the container.

Is it true that my application cannot access the contents of the secret without running with elevated permissions?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: @Konstantin - Alas, no, and now I'm off on other projects.